# Почему не работает Random

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста. Код совсем простой, правильный. Раньше, до переустановки работал.

```
package com.company;    
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomGlas = new Random(); // Объявляем Random
        int count = 0 + randomGlas.nextInt(100 - 0);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Рандомное число " +randomGlas);
    }
}
```

А выдаёт результат вот такой

```
Рандомное число java.util.Random@7530d0a
```

Я уже скачал новую версию Java, 3 раза переустановил Intellij IDEA. Без вас не справлюсь(

Comment: `System.out.println("Рандомное число " + count);`

Comment: 0 прибавлять не нужно, кстати

Comment: Так а что вы хотели сказать этим `System.out.println("Рандомное число " +randomGlas);`???

Comment: Спасибо большое что помогаете. У меня просто не работала программа, я стал проверять почему, упростил. Тут просто хотел проверить корректность вывода любого рандомного числа, и оказалось не зря(

Comment: @ДядяФёдор, ни на что не намекаю, но почитайте ["Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) )

Answer (score 1):

@Дядя Фёдор, для получения рандомного числа можно и не заморачиваться с классом Random.
Можно обойтись встроенным классом Math. Вот так:

```
int a = 3, b = 24;
int count = (int) (Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
System.out.println("Рандомное число " + count);
```

где a и b - границы диапазона из которого требуется взять случайное число

Answer (score 1):

Ваше случайное число лежит в `count`, а в `randomGlas` лежит объект - "поставщик" случайных чисел. Чтобы получить очередное целочисленное случайное число, у этого объекта нужно вызвать метод `nextInt()`:

```
package com.company;    
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomGlas = new Random(); // Объявляем Random
        int count = randomGlas.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Случайное число " + count);
        System.out.println("Еще одно случайное число " + randomGlas.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Заработало